# Docker image mounting the existing data volume for nexus

Tags: docker, nexus

1. I have added new repositories on nexus 3.17. There is no data, just repos.
2. Created .bak files
3. Created a docker image for nexus(call it newimage).

I have data from the current version(3.3.1) on a volume and I want the data to show up in the new nexus. When I try below the docker run command and go to nexus, new repositories do not show up, but data is there for old repos.

`docker run  -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v <local-docker-volume>:/nexus-data newimage`

The Dockerfile I use to create an image

```
FROM sonatype/nexus3:3.17.0  
COPY path-to-bak-files/*.bak /nexus-data/restore-from-backup/
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

p.s: let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: can you share the Dockerfile once? The idea is to have enough data in post so that others can also reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have added the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1):

As per your dockerfile you are copying the contents to `/nexus-data/restore-from-backup/` but while running the container you are mounting the existing volume on `/nexus-data` which ends up masking the `/nexus-data` directory on file system inside the container (where you added the data while image creation).

Important thing to note in mount operation is that if you mount another disk/share (in this case volume) on an existing directory on your file system(FS), you can't access the dir from your FS anymore. Thus, when you created docker image, you added some files to /nexus-data/restore-from-backup/ but when you mounted volume on /nexus-data, you mounted it over dir in your FS so you can't see files now from your FS.

To address the issue, you can do the following:

- add the data to a different location in dockerfile say `location1`
- create container with volume mount as you are currently doing
- use entrypoint OR command to copy the files from `location1` to `/nexus-data/restore-from-backup/`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I am not sure what do you meant by adding the data to a different location in Dockerfile"? Can you explain? Also, why mounting the volume as read-only? I don't want it to be read-only.
Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Even after following the steps you mentioned, the new repositories do not show up. I just decided to go with no volume so that new repos are there.